# blank rows while exporting the data as csv file in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

I need to export the db content as csv file in my Application.It is working. But the content is not start from the first row. Its starts from 40th row.What I have to do more in that?

```
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header("Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header('Content-Type: text/csv, charset=UTF-8; encoding=UTF-8');
$filename = date('Y_m_d_s');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename.".csv\"");

if($dbResult) {
    $cnthead=0; $cntr =count($dbResult[0])-1;
    foreach($dbResult[0] as $key => $Val){ 
        echo $key;
        if($cnthead < $cntr) {
            echo ",";
            $cnthead++;
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
    foreach($dbResult as $dbRes){
        $cntcontnt=0;
        foreach($dbRes as $dbVal){ 
            echo $dbVal; 
            if($cntcontnt < $cntr) {
                echo ",";
                $cntcontnt++;
            }
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}
```

$dbResult array is like below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Appraisee Name] => aaa R
            [Team] => Software
            [Appraisee Emp No] => -
            [Appraiser Name] => vvv A
            [Appraiser Emp No] => -
            [Reviewer Name] => sss S
            [Reviewer Emp No] => -
            [Current Appraisal Status] => start
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Appraisee Name] => gan R
            [Team] => Software
            [Appraisee Emp No] => -
            [Appraiser Name] => fcv R
            [Appraiser Emp No] => -
            [Reviewer Name] => sss S
            [Reviewer Emp No] => -
            [Current Appraisal Status] => start
        ) 
)
```

Comment: check your query result before processing csv.

Comment: can you paste $dbResult values for my reference

Comment: i guess the problem is $cntr =count($dbResult[0])-1; it gives the count of your first record. suppossed you need to change it to your result count if you need the all result. or you need to have this code for any specific?

Answer (score 1):

I had the blank line on top problem.
I added 
ob_end_clean();
before writing to file and the problem was res

Answer (score 0):

i guess problem starts here

`$cntr =count($dbResult[0])-1; //so $cntr = 7;`

```
foreach($dbResult[0] as $key => $Val){ 
    echo $key;
    if($cnthead < $cntr) {//this condition only true for first 7 loops after it will fails
        echo ",";
        $cnthead++;
    }
}
```

for instance, $dbResult has more than 7 records it will do not go into first forloop if statement.if you want to loop $dbResult all records then change your code as below.

i guess you need to change

```
$cntr =count($dbResult[0])-1;
```

into

```
$cntr =count($dbResult)-1;
```

try this change in your code

Comment: foreach statements are working smoothly. Before the content in CSV,some blank rows also displayed. How to avoid that space in CSV export. That is my problem in this.

Comment: i guess this is your csv data $dbVal since if($dbVal != '') {echo $dbVal; 
            if($cntcontnt < $cntr) {
                echo ",";
                $cntcontnt++;
            } }

Comment: can you send me your csv?

Comment: Hi @sudhakar, I solved this problem. In my php file , I left 2 lines blankly. Because of that only blank rows were displayed in CSV. Thank u  for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user2063756, you pointed me on the right direction. 
My CSV file was starting at the 4th row. 
Simply because I was using a PHP include file of my constants....and this file had an empty line before the "

WAS
"

instead of 
"